# Taking the limit of two exponential functions

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given
>
> $$\exp(\epsilon (A+B))=\exp(\epsilon A)\exp(\epsilon B)(1+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)) \tag{1}$$
>
> Where A, B are real square matrices.
>
> Implies
> $$\exp(A+B)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(\exp(A/n)\exp(B/n))^n \tag{2}$$

I want to show $(2)$. I was trying to evaluate the RHS as follows

$$\exp^n(A/n)\exp^n(B/n) = \left( 1+\frac{A}{n} + \mathcal{O}(A^2)\right)^n\left( 1+\frac{B}{n} + \mathcal{O}(B^2)\right)^n \tag{3}$$

But I do not see how taking $n \to \infty$ in $(3)$ is going to lead to $\exp(A+B)$

Am I on the right track? Should I approach it in a different way instead?

Comment: No, you are going on the wrong track here.  $[\exp(A/n)]^n[\exp(N/n)]^n=\exp(A)\exp(B)\neq\exp(A+B)$ for matrices $A,B$.

Comment: I see, that is due to BCH formula. So how should I approach it instead?

Comment: *Hint*: $\exp(A+B)=[\exp(\frac1n(A+B))]^n$ and you know $\exp(\frac1n(A+B))=\exp(\frac1nA)\exp(\frac1nB)(I+O(n^{-2}))$.  You will need to be a bit more careful when you try to pull the $I+O(n^{-2})$ out to avoid the $O(n^2)$ commutator growing this by too much.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you, I will think about it

Comment: @user10354138 alright I see that ,(if I am not mistaken), all reduces to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \mathcal{O}(n^{-2}))^n=1$ But I do not know how to evaluate this limit...